# OpenLayers-3 ol.proj.transform not working with custom projection

Tags: javascript, transform, projection, openlayers-3

I am struggling to get transform working with a custom projection. My map is in New Zealand Transverse Mercator (EPSG:2193). I want to convert coordinates back to EPSG:4326 (long/lat) when I click on a map. Here is where I declare the projection, set up the map and the click event handler:

```
<script src="http://epsg.io/2193.js"></script>
<script src="http://epsg.io/4326.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js"></script>   

var nztmproj = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:2193',
  extent: [827933.23, 3729820.29, 3195373.59, 7039943.58]
});
ol.proj.addProjection(nztmproj)
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: nztmproj,
    center: [1824728.56,5534935.14],
    resolutions: [4233.333333,3175,2116.666667,1058.333333,529.1666667,264.58333333,132.2916667,92.60416667,66.14583333,39.6875,26.45833333,19.84375,13.22916667,9.260416667,6.614583333,5.291666667,3.96875,2.645833333,1.984375,1.322916667,0.661458333,0.264583333,0.132291667],
    zoom: 19
  })
});
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var coord = evt.coordinate;
  var mygeom = new ol.geom.Point(coord);
  mygeom.transform(ol.proj.transform(nztmproj, 'EPSG:4326'));
  var newcoord = mygeom.getCoordinates();
  var lon = newcoord[0];
  var lat = newcoord[1];
  var element = overlay.getElement();
  element.innerHTML = lon + "," + lat;
  overlay.setPosition(coord);
  map.addOverlay(overlay);
});
```

When I try to click on the map, I get a TypeError: destinationProjection is null

Answer (score 0):

If you would set up a jsfiddle you would have seen the error on

```
ol.proj.addProjection(nztmproj)
```

correct:

```
ol.proj.addProjection(nztmproj);
```

Not sure, what you want to do with this:

```
mygeom.transform(ol.proj.transform(nztmproj, 'EPSG:4326'));
```

But wouldn't be it easier to transform the evt.coordinates first?
like:

```
var coord = ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, nztmproj, 'EPSG:4326');
```

I'm pretty sure this will not output any valid EPSG:4326-coordinates (see [APIdoc](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.proj.html#addCoordinateTransforms)) but it's about the scheme 'transformfunction(coordinates,fromprojection,toprojection)